# SharePoint Online List Lookup within the Same List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column

1. I have only One SharePoint Online List.
2. I want to use a Lookup using "ID" and "Prior ID" columns, in order get a Date added to the "Prior Date" Field.
3. I want it to look like the table below.
4. But currently, nothing is returned in the Prior Date field, it is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample list for your reference:

[image]

Please see the process as following:

1. Create a lookup column named “Prior ID” and choose to retrieve data from the current list.
2. Under “Add a column to show each of these additional fields”, select “Date”.

[image]

3. The additional column will display as “Prior ID:Date” in the list view. You can then rename the column as “Prior Date”, so that the list will eventually display as you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank YOU!!!!!!!  I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, and you explained it so very simply.  I am so grateful to you for taking the time.